# Running MS Access through Python

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access file with 4 buttons that a user has to click 1 by 1 after the previous task completes.

I am trying to automate the file without changing its code. Is it possible to automate it with some library?

There is what the code looks like in Visual Basic

```
Private Sub Command61_Click()

Call Clear_Feed_Tables

End Sub

Private Sub Command63_Click()

Call Import_Feeds

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Python's COM library, `win32com`, to access the MS Access' object library (same process VBA does). Specifically, call the [Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run) method. Below assumes both methods reside in a standard module (i.e., not behind a form or report). Also, this method does not use any form values (i.e., `Forms!myForm!myControl`). If user enters values, re-write methods to pass parameters and then have Python pass same values.

```
import win32com.client

# OPEN ACCESS APP AND DATABASE
oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(r'C:\Path\To\myDB.accdb')

# RUN STANDARD MODULE METHODS
oApp.Run("Clear_Feed_Tables")
oApp.Run("Import_Feeds")

oApp.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
oApp.Quit
oApp = None
```